# Screen locks itself after call

Tags: samsung-galaxy-s-2, lock-screens, calls

I have a Samsung Galaxy SII GT-9100 with Android Jelly Bean 4.1.2 XXLS8. I am using a PIN for my screen lock. If I make a call while my phone is unlocked, when the call is ended the screen goes to the lock. It is really annoying. How can I fix this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a general problem with all Android phones. Best way to solve this problem is `On Call End` program. It provides user to select following actions to take after a call:

- Do nothing
- Go to phone Home screen
- Go to phone Dialer
- Vibrate
- Show a toast message with the call duration. Outgoing call duration includes the ringing time.

You can install `On Call End` from here:
https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.brosix.callend&hl=tr

Answer (score 1):

Try disconnecting the call before the other side hangs up.

I've noticed a similar behavior in ICS 4.0, where if I disconnect the call first the phone does not lock.

Comment: Interesting :) I will try it.